# Row selection using forEachNode very slow

Tags: ag-grid

I am using AG Grid React. I have a thousand row of data. I am trying to select a range of rows based upon their indices.

```
    gridOptions.api.forEachNode(node => {
        if (node.childIndex >= startIndex && node.childIndex < endIndex) {
            node.setSelected(true)
        }
    });
```

This is turning out to be very sow and typically takes 30 seconds on the UI. Seems like `setSelected` triggers multiple render cycles. What is the correct way of doing it?

Comment: AG is just slow your code isn't wrong. Make sure you didn't turn off virtualisation though as that sounds slow even for AG. I had about 700 items and took a few seconds which seemed bad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is - `setSelected(newValue)` dispatches events. When we do it in a loop for a thousand items(*say*) - there are a thousand events, a thousand requests queued for asynchronous update in React which can be accounted for all the delay.

I fixed it using another version of `setSelected` - `setSelected(newValue, clearSelection, suppressFinishActions)`. Unfortunately, this is not written in the official documentation.
The idea is to use this version for *all but the last* selection, so that all the event dispatches are supressed and use the normal selection we have been using forever to select the last element so that it also triggers necessary events for `onRowSelected`, `onSelectionChanged`, etc. to work normally.

```
        this.api.forEachNodeAfterFilter(node => {
            if (node.childIndex >= startIndex && node.childIndex < endIndex) {
                selectedNodes.push(node);
            }
        });

        if (selectedNodes.length > 0) {
            // setSelected re-renders every time so use suppressFinishActions except last one
            for (let i = 0; i < selectedNodes.length - 1; i++) {
                selectedNodes[i].setSelected(true, false, true);
            }
            selectedNodes[selectedNodes.length - 1].setSelected(true);
        }
```

Comment: @Dominic Is this helpful in your case?

Comment: How to do this for server side row model?

Comment: @abksrv Thanks for the solution with clear explanation.

Comment: @abksrv Awesome solution..! Working like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use  pagination to load the chunk of data thane the whole data.
[Pagination Docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-pagination/#pagination-api)

Comment: Pagination may not help as minimum page size could be around 100 and this issue is significant even with 20-30 rows as well.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you don't have subscribed to any events that may cause your code to be slow, e.g. onRowSelected, onSelectionChanged. These get triggered for each

> node.setSelected(true)

If you do have any of these subscribed events, one possible way to solve this, is to unsubscribe before the loop and then re-subscribe after the loop.

Also, depending on your use case you may want to use

> forEachNodeAfterFilter(node)

in order to only loop through visible nodes instead of

> forEachNode(node)

Comment: I tried forEachNodeAfterFilter - similar results. I do have to something with the events that's why there is no point subscribing after selection.